# Riemann sums: Why is a limit used for integrals, or why can the bases of rectangles in the integral have length 0?

Tags: calculus

When $\Delta x$ is the length of the partition of an interval $[a,b]$ in definite integration and $\Delta x = (b-a) /n$ then if $n = \infty$ the multiplication of a given function $f(x_{i})$ is by $0$. I don't get the notation or what to do because there is not division by $0$ however putting $n=\infty$ in $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ makes all the integrals I do equal to $0$.

Put another way... how does the series converge to a number?

Comment: The width of the rectangles is not $0$, but rather approaches $0$.

Comment: That's my question but now that I am reconsidering it how is that a single value? The way I remember to get one is by plugging in the value that the limit approaches.

Comment: $n$ is never $\infty.$ $\infty$ is not a number. This is why we take limits.

Comment: If you want to go without limits, instead of using the generic $\infty$ you can use the more specific hyperreal infinity, $\omega$.  $\frac{1}{\omega}$ is not 0 but $\epsilon$ (an infinitesimal number).  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mentioned the key here is understand the idea of limits (of sequences). So let's look at an example. Let's calculate:

$$\int_0^1 x^2 dx $$

If we split the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ distinct subintervals $[0,\frac{1}{n}],[\frac{1}{n},
\frac{2}{n}],...,[\frac{n-1}{n},1]$ and use the right-handed end-point definition of Riemann Integral we get that

$$\mathcal{R}_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n^3}\left(\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}\right)=\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{6n}+\frac{1}{6n^2}$$

Then we take the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ to get
$$\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

“Plugging in” $\infty$ might sometimes work, but you have to know how to do it, because $\infty$ is not a number, and it won’t always work. As $n\to\infty,$ the rectangles get thinner and thinner, but there are also more and more of them.

It is somewhat amazing that there is one limit, rather than a lot of limit points. This is practically the definition of a function being Riemann integrable.

There are functions that are not Riemann integrable, so the limit doesn’t always exist. But it does exist when the functions are “nice.” Certainly if they are continuous. But we have to prove this, it is not something we can merely assert. (Proving it is often beyond an intro to calculus course, but it might be done if the class/book is intended for more interested math students.)

As for why you can’t just “plug in $\infty,$” we have limits like:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}=\ln 2$$

and:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac\pi4$$

Both of these are limits of Riemann sums(*), but you aren’t going to get the limits by any intuitive “substitution” of $\infty$ for $n.$

In particular, the rectangles as $n\to\infty$ get thinner and thinner, but there are also more and more of them. So the limit is like an $\infty\cdot 0$ case. The individual terms in the sums go to $0,$ but the number of terms goes to infinity.

You will need a finer notion of what a limit is other than mere substitution. There are lots of limits that are not mere substitutions.

For example, you might have learned a way to calculate square roots by hand. You start with an estimate, and then you get a better and better estimate, this is a limit process. You never can write out all the digits of $\sqrt3,$ but as the number of steps you follow the process gets larger, the more digits accuracy you have. There is no way to “substitute infinity” into that process. You need to show the limit is correct using subtler means.

---

(*) The first limit is the Riemann sum for:

$$\int_1^2\frac1x\,dx$$ The second: $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$$